# Error on columns order - extracting text with PDFbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to strip the text of a PDF document but the columns are out of order. I'm getting the last column as the first.

How I can reorder it? See document [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByHzULw2viydekhXSTVuS0NVYTA).

Comment: The problem simply is that your document first draws the right-most column and then the others left to right; thus, your PDFBox text extraction code returns the contents in that order. Instead of using the existing order, you could ask PDFBox to order by position, but that would not help as this ordering does not see the columnar structure of the document and would extract top to bottom (across column borders!) and then left-to-right  in those assumed text lines.

Comment: If the PDFs you extract the text from have fixed positions of the text columns, you could try with extraction by area, column by column. Otherwise you have to do layout analysis to an extent that goes beyond the focus of PDFBox. You can use PDFBox, though, to produce the data required for such layout analysis, and "merely" have to implement the intelligence that recognizes the layout. Due to the presence of the lines dividing the columns, this looks not too complicated here; as we do not know what documents you have to extract from in general, it is unclear whether that approach is helpful.

Comment: I think that I will need to analyze the layout taking as a reference the vertical lines, but it will not be very easy because the document is all unpredictable, [see this page.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByHzULw2viydaDd2TjRZRE1rVWs/view)

Comment: Did you read the PDFBox FAQ? "Why does the extracted text appear in the wrong sequence?" https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#textorder

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Non-trivial indeed... It even took me as a human (who is used to identify text flow patterns) some time to recognize the correct order of partial columns... Furthermore, you will find out that extracting tabular data is a challenge in itself... Is there no machine-readable version of the Diário Oficial?